# Application design for parallel collection processing

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, concurrency

I'm experimenting with the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace but I have a problem implementing my design.

1. My input queue (ConcurrentQueue) is getting populated fine from a Thread which is doing some I/O at startup to read and parse.
2. Next I kick off a Parallel.ForEach() on the input queue. I'm doing some I/O bound work on each item.
3. A log item is created for each item processed in the ForEach() and is dropped into a result queue.

What I would like to do is kick off the logging I start reading the input because I  may not be able to fit all of the log items in memory. What is the best way to wait for items to land in the result queue?  Are there design patterns or examples that I should be looking at?

Comment: Can you not use a simple BlockingCollection<T> from System.Collections.Concurrent?  Presumably, the type would be some 'LogEntry'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pattern you're looking for is the [producer/consumer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). More specifically, you can have a producer/consumer [implementation built around TPL and BlockingCollection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx).

The main concepts you want to read about are:

1. [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx),
2. [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx),
3. [TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx)(will allow you to perform some action when a set of tasks/threads is finished running).
4. Bounding and Blocking in [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx). This allows you to set a maximum size for your output collection (for memory reasons) and producer thread(s) will wait for consumers to pick up elements in case the maximum size you specify is reached.
5. [BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) and [BlockingCollection.IsCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267315.aspx) which can be used to synchronize producers and consumers (producer can say when it's finished, consumer can check for that and keep running until the producer(s) are finised).

A more complete sample is in the second article I linked.

In your case I think you want the consumer to just pick up things from the result queue and dispose of them as soon as possible (write them to a logging store, or similar).

So your final collection, where you dump log items should be a `BlockingCollection`, not a `ConcurrentQueue`.